# Modifying content type INPUT page?

Tags: drupal, content-type

Lets say I create a content type, called "product". Now, if I wish to change the way product nodes are displayed, i would edit "node-product.tpl.php". Easy enough. But what if I want to edit the INPUT page? I.e. The page where you CREATE the node? Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be a little bit polemic, the answer is no, there isn't an "easy" way :]

You have some possibilities:

1. The classic: use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) to alter [single fields](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6) modifying the `$form array`. (you can prepend and append HTML too with the `#markup` directive).
2. Use `$form['#theme'] = 'my_theme_function'` and create a `my_theme_function($form)` that
   renders the complete form itself, i.e.:

   ```
   function my_theme_function($form) {
       // some calls to drupal_render( $form['my_field'] );
       return drupal_render($form);
   }
   ```
3. Use something like the [`form_panel`](http://drupal.org/project/form_panel) module...

(There is a lot of literature about this topic in Drupal forums.)

Answer (score 2):

This page has a good overview of working with input forms for CCK: http://drupal.org/node/101092